# video tag take up full browser space

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to have my video take up the whole browser size when I enter the page. However I am seeing a bit of the next `<div>`

[image]

Here is the HTML for the page:

[image]

Here is the CSS for the `video-containter`:

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    background: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

The `<section>` with `class="index"` contains nothing:

```
.index {

}
```

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670874/is-there-an-equivalent-to-background-size-cover-and-contain-for-image-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use vh and vw as @theStreets93 suggested but I find I get better results when it's applied to the body and html, then make a child element (such as `.video-container`) at 100%. Making the body and html `relative` and `.video-container` `absolute` will give you complete control by setting `top, bottom, left,` and `right` to 0, but it might stretch and distort your video so adjust accordingly. The resets of `margin, padding,` and `border` as well as `box-sizing: border-box/inherit` should counteract UA defaults like that irritating 8px `margin` added to body.

I noticed that in your HTML `.video-container` is not a child of body and that you have several children of body as well. I suggest that you trim some of the superfluous elements and set the elements you do require to a height or line-height of 0 if possible. You might have to unwrap `.video-container` as well if your'e able to. Of course you might not have to do all that stripping away if the rest of your elements are static (i.e. `position: static` which is default).
It's hard to tell since you haven't provided a proper demo. :\

```
html, body { 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    font: 400 16px/1.45 'Source Code Pro';
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    border: 0;
}

.video-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -100;
    background: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I now have my CSS set to this: http://dpaste.com/2AW34XW This fills up the browser page but as I drag teh browser. I notice that the text starts to overlap the video. http://postimg.org/image/6ktgk93kx/

Comment: I managed to create a jsfiddle!: https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/  If you dragged the window around. You can see the text overlap the video

Answer (score 2):

Are you try with **vw** and **vh** ?

```
.video-container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: relative;
    background: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

- vh (viewport height)
- vw (viewport width)