# Display img tag like background-size: contain

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to get a similar effect like `background-size: contain` with an `img` tag?

I want to display product pictures inside a fixed width/height div container, that have various dimensions (square, portrait, landscape). The pictures should

- Always display the whole image, nothing should be cropped
- Be aligned horizontally and vertically centered

This is, what `background-size: contain` does. Unfortunately I have to use an `img` tag (vor various reasons, going from the framework I use to SEO stuff).

In this plnkr you can see the problems and how it should look like (using `background-size`) http://plnkr.co/edit/k9Nv4ELoZgYCaQfVuSDQ?p=preview

1. Looks good
2. Should be centered vertically
3. Is cropped, but should display 100% of its height

CSS:

```
.product {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.product img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

> **Note:** Somehow I can't insert HTML tags, it displays the images not the
>   source code. Please have a look into the plnkr.

EDIT:

> - This should work with CSS only, no JS.
> - Support for all modern browsers, including IE 10

Comment: `Object-fit` might be an option here.

Comment: for `object-fit` there is no IE support, see here http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Comment: You might want to add the support requirements into the question then. Frankly though this looks like a job for javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an equivalent to background-size: cover and contain for image elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670874/is-there-an-equivalent-to-background-size-cover-and-contain-for-image-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add this css:

```
.product img {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height:200px;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this by setting `position: relative` to the `.product` and `position: absolute` with other formatting to the `.product img`. Please check the fiddle below.

```css
.product-css {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.product {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.product img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  bottom: -100%;
  left: -100%;
  right: -100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<h2>With img tag</h2> 1.
<div class="product">
  <img src="http://keentype.com/post-images/wineBottles/vine-bottles-post.jpg">
</div>

2.
<div class="product">
  <img src="https://0.s3.envato.com/files/149175458/wine_bottle_mockup_05.jpg">
</div>

3.
<div class="product">
  <img src="http://www.designer-daily.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/boxhead-wine.jpg">
</div>

<hr>

<h2>Desired behaviour (with background-image)</h2>

<div class="product-css" style="background-image: url(http://keentype.com/post-images/wineBottles/vine-bottles-post.jpg)">
</div>

<div class="product-css" style="background-image: url(https://0.s3.envato.com/files/149175458/wine_bottle_mockup_05.jpg)">
</div>

<div class="product-css" style="background-image: url(http://www.designer-daily.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/boxhead-wine.jpg)">
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, thanks Patrick. Should be the accepted answer.