# How to make images in carousel responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a carousel that has three images and when it scrolls another set of three images are being displayed. But the images are not responsive. Here is my code and a screenshot.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <h5 id="textColor">Consecteteur Eliptois eliot</h5>
      <div id="carouselIndicators1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselIndicators1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselIndicators1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselIndicators1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="carouselbox.jpg" alt="First slide" style="padding-right:6px;">
            <!-- Static Header -->
            <div class="header-text hidden-xs">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <h5>
                  <span><strong>Image1</strong></span><br /> Lorem Ipsum
                </h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /header-text -->
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="carouselbox.jpg" alt="First slide" style="padding-right:6px;">
            <!-- Static Header -->
            <div class="header-text2 hidden-xs" id="secondslide">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <h5>
                  <span><strong>Image1</strong></span><br /> Lorem Ipsum
                </h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /header-text -->
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="carouselbox.jpg" alt="First slide">
            <!-- Static Header -->
            <div class="header-text3 hidden-xs" id="secondslide">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <h5>
                  <span><strong>Image1</strong></span><br /> Lorem Ipsum
                </h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /header-text -->
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="carouselbox.jpg" alt="Second slide" style="padding-right:6px;">
            <!-- Static Header -->
            <div class="header-text hidden-xs" id="secondslide">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <h5>
                  <span><strong>Image1</strong></span><br /> Lorem Ipsum
                </h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /header-text -->
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="carouselbox.jpg" alt="Second slide" style="padding-right:6px;">
            <!-- Static Header -->
            <div class="header-text2 hidden-xs" id="secondslide">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <h5>
                  <span><strong>Image1</strong></span><br /> Lorem Ipsum
                </h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /header-text -->
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="carouselbox.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            <!-- Static Header -->
            <div class="header-text3 hidden-xs" id="secondslide">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <h5>
                  <span><strong>Image1</strong></span><br /> Lorem Ipsum
                </h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /header-text -->
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="carouselbox.jpg" alt="Third slide" style="padding-right:6px;">
            <!-- Static Header -->
            <div class="header-text hidden-xs" id="secondslide">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <h5>
                  <span><strong>Image1</strong></span><br /> Lorem Ipsum
                </h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /header-text -->
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="carouselbox.jpg" alt="Third slide" style="padding-right:6px;">
            <!-- Static Header -->
            <div class="header-text2 hidden-xs" id="secondslide">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <h5>
                  <span><strong>Image1</strong></span><br /> Lorem Ipsum
                </h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /header-text -->
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="carouselbox.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            <!-- Static Header -->
            <div class="header-text3 hidden-xs" id="secondslide">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <h5>
                  <span><strong>Image1</strong></span><br /> Lorem Ipsum
                </h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /header-text -->
            <a href="" style="margin-top:55px;margin-left:12px;"><strong>Next</strong></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselIndicators1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselIndicators1" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <!--end of carousel indicators-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdhYp.png)

Comment: Please see this post and apply it to the image element https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670874/is-there-an-equivalent-to-background-size-cover-and-contain-for-image-elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an equivalent to background-size: cover and contain for image elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670874/is-there-an-equivalent-to-background-size-cover-and-contain-for-image-elements)

Answer (score 0):

make an inner bootstrap row for 3 images and add `img-responsive` class to all images and remove extra padding and margins

```html
   

 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid img-responsive" src="carouselbox.jpg" alt="First slide">
            <!-- Static Header -->
            <div class="header-text hidden-xs">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <h5>
                      <span><strong>Image1</strong></span><br /> Lorem Ipsum
                    </h5>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /header-text -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid img-responsive" src="carouselbox.jpg" alt="First slide">
            <!-- Static Header -->
            <div class="header-text2 hidden-xs" id="secondslide">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <h5>
                  <span><strong>Image1</strong></span><br /> Lorem Ipsum
                </h5>
              </div>
            </div>
         <!-- /header-text -->
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <img class="d-block img-fluid img-responsive" src="carouselbox.jpg" alt="First slide">
            <!-- Static Header -->
            <div class="header-text3 hidden-xs" id="secondslide">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <h5>
                  <span><strong>Image1</strong></span><br /> Lorem Ipsum
                </h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /header-text -->
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That works great thanks! but the images are so small when  the screen is very small that the text is getting cut. Is there a way on very small screen, I can make one image in a slide instead of three images in a slide?