# What is the difference between object-fit:cover and background-size: cover?

Tags: html, css, image

I’m facing a need to have a “cover” background on one of the elements.

What are pros and cons of using CSS `background-size: cover` vs actual `img` with `object-fit: cover`?

Comment: background-size: cover is far better supported and just as good in the RWD department. Plus the age-old "don't use the <img> element for backgrounds".

Comment: You might see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670874/is-there-an-equivalent-to-background-size-cover-and-contain-for-image-elements) before asking a new one,
take look ;)

Comment: For one thing, they are used on **different** elements.

Comment: @Paulie_D my question was edited by someone else: I'm not asking what the difference, I'm asking what are pros and cons of using one over another.

Comment: Which, unfortunately, pushes this into `opinion` territory which is off-topic,

Comment: You should really ask about the technical differences. That seems to be a on-topic question. Asking about pros and cons is opinion-based.

Comment: depends if you want to print the image or not and if you want it to be part of a page for screen readers or not and lastly whether you need to support ie or not (most object fit polyfills fall back to background size anyway)

Answer (score 12):

In addition to what others have said about compatibility (`background-size: cover` is supported on all modern browsers, where `object-fit: cover` is not), a potentially unwanted side-effect of using a `div` element with `background-size: cover` is that if the user tries to print your page, a lot of times the image won't be printed as it will be deemed a background by the browser and ignored.

That might not matter to you at all, but it is something to be aware of.

There are [some ways to get around this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670151/how-can-i-force-browsers-to-print-background-images-in-css), but I don't know of a single, cross-browser silver bullet method.