# WooCommerce: Show full size image in smartphones

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have one issue with showing properly thumbnails from my WooCommerce products into smartphones. Issue is that is not shown into full size only on smartphones, however, it is showing fine in desktop version. For example:

**Desktop version preview**:

[image: Desktop Preview]

**Smartphone version preview** (images are cuted);

[image: Check smartphone preview]

Any help how to fix this issue? I tried to regenerate thumbnails, but problem persisted still.

Comment: *Duplicate*. You want to use `background-size: contain;` (instead of cover) in the second solution of this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670874/is-there-an-equivalent-to-background-size-cover-and-contain-for-image-elements#answer-26967278

Comment: Great. Your answer solve my question. Many thanks

Comment: No problem, glad it helped