# How to do aspect-radio in picture inside a grid?

Tags: html, css

I have set of pictures in different sizes displayed in css-grid.

How to display all the pictures to be display in 1.6 aspect radio?

In my code I need to have three columns in row. `grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;`.

But the pictures are changing the item size and not in right aspect radio and I have a lot of white space in the picture.

What is missing in my code?

Here is the code:

```css
.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.wrap .item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap .item img {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 270px;
  max-height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/562/500/300"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/588/500/500"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/563/400/350"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/564/500/400"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/565/300/300"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/566/270/180"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: just edited....

Comment: Good, thank you for the edit.  My gut feeling is you need to change them from image elements, and instead make them background images within the `<div>` with a `background-size:cover`.  Although it doesn't feel like a great solution, so I'm resisting making it an actual answer

Comment: I can't change the html.. it must be have img tag

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26967278/930393

Comment: If the images are different sizes, then `grid` is not a good option for laying them out....because it won't be a grid.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate rule for `img` tag and specify how the image should fit the `div` elements via `object-fit`

```css
.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.wrap .item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap .item {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 270px;
  max-height: 180px;
}

img {
   width: 100%,
   height: 100%,
   object-fit: cover


}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/562/500/300"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/588/500/500"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/563/400/350"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/564/500/400"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/565/300/300"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/566/270/180"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry but its not good enough. the pictures are have space between which is not good. the picture can be grow by this parent div but still keep radio 1.6

Comment: @JonSud I don't see any space between the pictures when I run the snippet. Every picture fits to the container perfectly. Now the problem is, that you cannot have both a specific aspect ration and a container outside the very aspect aspect ratio - and no white space.

Comment: click on "expand snippet" and play with the size of the chrome. you will see

Comment: I see. Now, ween the browser is shrink ed, what is the expected output?

Comment: three columns in row inside each col have img with display of 1.6 aspect-radio. without space between the columns, please

Comment: But this will introduce white space when shrinking - because the images will have to stick to a specific dimension regardless of the container side.

Comment: correct. I think in shrink under the picture height it will be okay to have white space. I think. but the idea is the column should be have the aspect radio in the picture should be fit inside right?

Answer (score 0):

### Determine the size in the grid

I use `object-fit: cover;` to cover ther size, you can use also `object-fit: cotain;` but you may see blank areas

```css
.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 270px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 180px);
}
.wrap .item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap .item img {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/562/500/300"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/588/500/500"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/563/400/350"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/564/500/400"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/565/300/300"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/566/270/180"></div>
</div>
```

### Use vw OR %

You can use also with vw to change size:

```css
.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 32vw);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 20vw);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 33.33333%);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 22.2222%);
}
.wrap .item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap .item img {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/562/500/300"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/588/500/500"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/563/400/350"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/564/500/400"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/565/300/300"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/566/270/180"></div>
</div>
```

### After comments

You can do like this, not much clear

```css
.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
.wrap .item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 22vw;
}
.wrap .item img {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/562/500/300"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/588/500/500"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/563/400/350"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/564/500/400"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/565/300/300"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/566/270/180"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the .item should be in 1.6 aspect-radio and the image should be fit.

Comment: I add new solution, what do you think?