# How to add gif to background

Tags: html, css

I've used the following CSS and I wonder if I can change the background to use some gif i.e. instead of background:white use the following gif as background http://media.giphy.com/media/8OUdE03f3Nauc/giphy_s.gif

```
#carousel figure {

    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 111px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    background: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: solid 1px black;

}
```

ive tried with 
background: url('http://media.giphy.com/media/8OUdE03f3Nauc/giphy_s.gif');

and also this

background-image:'http://media.giphy.com/media/8OUdE03f3Nauc/giphy_s.gif'
which is not working...

Comment: add your code jsfiddle

Comment: w3schools.com/tags/tag_figure.asp hi dear, please read it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913359/can-figure-tag-in-html5-be-used-for-background-images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this: Its working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1v5njdha/)**

```
#carousel  {       
    background: white url("http://media.giphy.com/media/8OUdE03f3Nauc/giphy_s.gif") no-repeat center; 
// Added your gif background along with your code */
}
```

Comment: I try it and it doesnt work for me what could be the problem?

Comment: post your relevant html / css code  to help you better

Comment: ive added the no-repeat-center and now it works :) thank you 1+

Comment: If my code helped you accept that as answer, that will help others who is looking for same kind of solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following:

```
#carousel figure {

display: block;
position: absolute;
width: 150px;
height: 111px;
left: 10px;
top: 10px;
background: url('http://media.giphy.com/media/8OUdE03f3Nauc/giphy_s.gif');
overflow: hidden;
border: solid 1px black;
```

}

Comment: I try it and it doesnt work for me what could be the problem?

Comment: you might need to download the gif and put it in a local folder